# Linux kernel - is there a readahead/prefetch mechanism for writes?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, operating-system, prefetch

I know that readahead is a form of prefetching in the Linux kernel, except I have the notion that prefetching is more about hardware (cache) pre-loading whereas readahead is an OS level behavior for loading into memory/RAM from disk. It seems that readahead is [only used](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/filemap.c#L2436) during reads but not for writes. I know "read" is in the name, but why isn't readahead/prefetching used for writes?

Following the suggestion [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question), I think I have an answer (posting below), but would like comments, suggestions, or better answers.

Comment: The main benefit of cache for writes is write-avoidance. If you do multiple writes to the same location, you only need the last one to go to disk.

Comment: Please don't add text in title which is not relevant to the question

Comment: @mightyWOZ sorry, was trying to be upfront about intentions

Comment: No need to be sorry, We are all here to help and get help, but having clear worded question makes the task of answerer a bit easy.

Comment: @stark So are you also saying that there is basically no benefit one can get from a readahead for writes? How do you feel about the logic of my answer?

Comment: @wxz Reads and writes are different paths in the kernel.  Reads are submitted synchronously since there is a task waiting for data.  Writes are flushed in the background to disk.  A partial write of the first block will trigger a read, but if you are writing full blocks no read is needed.  There is no predictive code from the write side that will  (or should) trigger reads.  Readahead is done when the read side detects a pattern of sequential access.

Comment: @stark one last question hopefully, you said "a partial write of the first block will trigger a read", why only the first block? Because the first block triggers read, which will do the readahead so then the next blocks won't trigger a read?

Comment: Why would you read a block you are going to write on?

Comment: @stark Because it's a partial write. If I'm only going to modify half a block, I still need to read that block to salvage the half that isn't being overwritten. If I happen to write to three consecutive blocks, but only overwrite half of each, then I still should need to read all three blocks, no?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "writeahead" specific mechanism because writes that would benefit from it already implicitly spawn a readahead.

Two write cases that come to mind are the 1) "modify file" write and 2) the "completely overwrite" write.

1. "Modify file" write - in this case, you know that you want to modify a file. The reason you don't need to have a "writeahead" mechanism for this write is because this type of write already implicitly includes a read. The program has to read in the file so that you can modify specific parts of the file. During that read, the kernel behind the scenes can already do a readahead to help with future reads or writes.
2. "Complete overwrite" write - here, you don't care what the contents of the file are, you just write completely new data to it. There is no need to read the file, the write (assuming it covers a single page of memory) could in theory be written on a fresh page in RAM and then marked for write back to disk. There's no indication that any prefetching is needed because past history (complete overwrite) didn't require reading/loading memory.